# Trouble accessing members of select-string output when input is a system.array

Tags: powershell, object, output, select-string

I am calling restAPIs and some of them return multiple results, I am trying use Select-String to get the correct line in the Array, but it returns a matchinfo object with a value starting with @{...  I can't get this value into a hashtable or object so I can extract a member from the string.

I tried converting the MatchInfo object to a string with out-string and then putting that result in a hashtable.  Get following error:

```
Cannot convert the "
@{id=352475; href=/api/v1/exports/458234/export_files/352475; export_id=458234; status=Available}
" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
```

Have a PSCustomObject with the following contents:

```
PS C:> $_expFilesRet
href                                                        export_files
----                                                        ------------
/api/v1/user_identities/289362/export_files                 {@{id=352475; 
href=/api/v1/exports/458234/export_files/3...
```

The export files method of the above is

```
PS C:\> $_ExpFilesRet.export_files.getType();
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

with the following value:

```
PS C:\> $_expFilesRet.export_files

                           id href                                              export_id status
                           -- ----                                              --------- ------
                       352475 /api/v1/exports/458234/exp...                        458234 Available
                       278697 /api/v1/exports/357459/exp...                        357459 Available
```

Attempted the following

```
PS C:\> $_temp=$_ExpFilesRet.export_files | select-string -pattern $_postret.export_files.export_id
PS C:\> $_temp

@{id=352475; href=/api/v1/exports/458234/export_files/352475; export_id=458234; status=Available}
PS C:\> $_temp=$_ExpFilesRet.export_files | select-string -pattern $_postret.export_files.export_id | out-str
ing -width 1000
PS C:\> $_temp

@{id=352475; href=/api/v1/exports/458234/export_files/352475; export_id=458234; status=Available}


PS C:\> [hashtable]$_temp=$_temp
Cannot convert the "
@{id=352475; href=/api/v1/exports/458234/export_files/352475; export_id=458234; status=Available}
" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
At line:1 char:1
+ [hashtable]$_temp=$_temp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

I am trying to get the value of ID (352475) from the resulting string in $_temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Where-Object` rather than `Select-String` to filter objects:

```
$_temp = $_ExpFilesRet.export_files |Where-Object export_id -eq $_postret.export_files.export_id |Select -Expand id
```